# error handling mkdir and chdir in C?

Tags: c, mkdir

I do not understand why after creating directory **mkdir** return different values. In this example i'm trying to make a directory ***if not*** so error handle ***otherwise*** go to this directory ***if not*** so error handle.

But it's not working as I want!
It shows me 'failed to create' but actually creates the directory.
If I read reference right it returns 0 when successes.

*Code:*

```
    char* dirName = "Output";
    FILE *output;

    if(!mkdir(dirName))
        if(chdir(dirName))
            printf("Permission to open a new directory is denied");
    else
        printf("Permission to create a new directory is denied");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly diagnosed by John Carpenter, the `else` relates to the second `if`.  Use braces to avoid this bug known as the dangling else issue.

There is another issue in your code: under Linux or BSD, the prototype for `mkdir` is:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

Do you include the system header files?

Not passing proper permissions, such as `0777` invokes undefined behavior, the syscall wrapper will pass indeterminate permissions, creating the directory with inconsistent permissions.

Here is a corrected version:

```
const char *dirName = "Output";

if (!mkdir(dirName, 0777)) {
    if (chdir(dirName)) {
        printf("Permission to open a new directory is denied");
    }
} else {
    printf("Permission to create a new directory is denied");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need curly braces around the `if` statement bodies so that the `else` is bound to the correct `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation of `mkdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html):

> Upon successful completion, mkdir() shall return 0. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned, no directory shall be created, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

Now, remember, in C `0` evaluates to `false`, non-zero evaluates to `true`. So, when you check `if( mkdir( ... ) )` you are essentially asking if `mkdir` returned non-zero. And -1 is non-zero, so you are asking whether `mkdir()` failed, not whether `mkdir()` succeeded.

What you want to do instead is `if( mkdir ( ... ) == 0 )`.

Also, in the event of failure, you have no reason to suppose that the reason of the failure was an "access denied" error.  Check `errno` and report the correct error accordingly.

Comment: Actually I just type it wrong in a question. In compiled code i have `if(!mkdir) if(chdir) error else error` And I still have an issue

Comment: I GOT IT. The problem was in else priority. Compiler thinks else statement belongs to the second scoped IF statement.